# Routine stops without errors Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really wierd bug with excel vba is driving me insane: I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim nomLibroFuente, nomLibro As String
Dim nomTab1, nomTab2, nomTab3, nomTab4 As String
Dim n, m, x, y, z As Integer
Dim totalTab1, totalTab2, totalTab3, totalTab4 As Integer
Dim RutaArchivo As Variant

Sub llenarLibro()

nomTab1 = "POSICION VEHICULO"
nomTab2 = "TIPO DE DAÑO"
nomTab3 = "GRAVEDAD DAÑO"
nomTab4 = "DAÑOS"
nomLibro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
On Error GoTo errorEjecucion
optimizarOn
RutaArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Archivo de Origen", _
                            filefilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls")
If RutaArchivo = False Then
    salirRutina
End If
Workbooks.Open Filename:=RutaArchivo
nomLibroFuente = ActiveWorkbook.Name

... some other stuff
end sub
```

Basically it just open a file of my choosing and process that information in the current book, the problem is that it sudden stops at **'Workbooks.Open Filename:=RutaArchivo'** without error or any message, it does opens the file and the code just stops running.

When I insert a breakpoint there and go line for line it works fine, but without the breakpoint it just open the book and stops running, no idea why this happens

**UPDATE**

So I found out that the problem happens if I run the script with a shorcut like "ctrl+shift+S" running directly within vba (F5) or using a shorcut without shift for example "ctrl+S" solves the problem, now why?

Comment: does it do it for any workbook selected in `GetOpenFilename` or just some? Do the workbooks have code triggered in the `Workbook_Open` event?

Comment: for any workbook it does the same

Comment: I guess the `optimizarOn` is one of those 'standard' Excel sub-routines where you are doing things with `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.EnableEvents` ? Suggest you comment that out and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi yes exactly, I already tried that and still stops running

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error after commenting out `optimizarOn` and `salirRutina`.  Perhaps there is something in the workbooks you are opening that is hanging the process, or a conflict. Try with a new workbook. Also, when you declare variables in VBA (`Dim`), you need to declare the type for each, else they will be of type Variant.  You cannot just put a single type at the end of the line, as you have done in your code.  Something like `Dim x as integer, y as integer, z as integer ...` is what is required here.